# Is there any psychological research into, or theory about, propositional attitude reports？

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind, belief, attitude

What do propositional attitudes such as belief and suspicion mean not just as logical (syntactic) conceptions but as something in the mind？ When I believe or feel skeptical about certain propositions or sentences, there seem to be certain passions or emotions which are the very things that drive me to defend or argue against a certain view. What, then, is a propositional attitude as an item of "embodied cognition"？ What is the psychological or neurological mechanism of it?

Comment: Not *quite* what you're looking for, but see [eliminative materialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/materialism-eliminative/). Also, the term "cognition" from Kant to the cognitivism debate in ethics was the conceptualist counterpart of the term "proposition" for realists (where conceptualism/realism are situated with respect to the question of general/universal objects). So cognitive science hopefully would have something to say about your question.

Comment: Indeed propositional attitudes such as belief *about* a certain sense of proposition may have the potential to turn the explicit into the more durable implicit as an embodied mark of intentionality of the conscious...

Comment: @KristianBerry Sorry for seeing your comment so late.  What puzzles me is that there seem to be some emotions or passions together with believes and unbelieves, for example if I believe the eliminative materialism, then I might be passionate to defend it and debate with others. And sometimes believes seem to be emotions themselves,especially when I believe a proposition for no reason such as an axiom（in fact, I doubt the infinite chain of reasoning and believe that all propositions should end up in an unreason one）. What`s the relation between the propositional attitudes and these emotions?

Comment: @DoubleKnot Sorry for seeing your comment so late. I know propositional attitudes are treated as being intentional. I just wonder how we form a propositional attitude and whether propositional attitudes are deeply related with emotions or even could be treated as certain emotions.

Comment: Propositional attitudes can have a definite finite range of degree of such attitude like forming a credence, but emotions seem not enjoying such definite range. Per Hume it's the emotions direct human beings while beliefs as propositional attitudes are mere means to be used to serve the master emotions' ends...